# can't import the named export 'computed' from non ecmascript module pinia and Vue 2

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, pinia

After installing Pinia on my Vue 2 project, and imported it in the main.js file
I got this error

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/pinia/dist/pinia.mjs 1147:44-52
Can't import the named export 'computed' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This Vue configuration should do the trick

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.mjs$/,
          include: /node_modules/,
          type: "javascript/auto"
        }
      ] 
    }
  }
}
```

As mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/vuejs/pinia/issues/675#issuecomment-919544784).