# [Vue2 + module federation]: Error in dependencies "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'warn')"

Tags: vue.js, webpack, webpack-module-federation, pinia

I'm trying to create a MicroFrontend in Vue2 using module federation, like Pinia provides a singleton behaviour about stores that could be awesome for use in module federation, the problem is when I inject this an error is prompt ( I make previous test in a unique application and that works )

That is the error:

[image]

And the piece of code relative is:
[image]

My configuration is the next:

**Child1:** Who exposed it's components contains this vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require('@vue/cli-service')
const {ModuleFederationPlugin} = require("webpack").container;
const deps = require("./package.json");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  publicPath: 'auto',
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
        new ModuleFederationPlugin({
            name: 'child1',
            filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
            exposes: {
              './ResultsPage': './src/pages/ResultsPage',
              './Test1Page' : './src/pages/Test1Page',
              './Test2Page' : './src/pages/Test2Page',
              './appStore' : './src/store/appStore.js'
            },
            shared: require("./package.json").dependencies,
          }),
    ],
  }
})
```

And the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "child2",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.17",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-mocha": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.8",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pinia": "~0.1.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

**Parent:** This is how works vue.config.js

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const { ModuleFederationPlugin } = require("webpack").container;
const ExternalTemplateRemotesPlugin = require("external-remotes-plugin");
const deps = require("./package.json");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new ModuleFederationPlugin({
        name: "microfrontends-library",
        remotes: {
          child1: "child1@http://localhost:3013/remoteEntry.js",
          //child2: "child2@http://localhost:3014/remoteEntry.js",
        },
        shared: require('./package.json').dependencies,
      })
    ],
  },
});
```

And its package.json

```
{
  "name": "parent",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "test:unit": "vue-cli-service test:unit",
    "lint": "vue-cli-service lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@vue/composition-api": "^1.7.0",
    "core-js": "^3.8.3",
    "pinia": "^2.0.17",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-router": "^4.1.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.16",
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.12.16",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-router": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "~5.0.0",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.1.3",
    "@vue/vue2-jest": "^27.0.0-alpha.2",
    "babel-jest": "^27.0.6",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.0.3",
    "jest": "^27.0.5",
    "sass": "^1.32.7",
    "sass-loader": "^12.0.0",
    "vue-cli-plugin-pinia": "~0.1.4",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14"
  }
}
```

In resume: I don't have a HTTP server because I'm making a build of the child and them using a HTTP server for support ( In the future I would like to add CDN to this children's )

All help would be accepted, really I'm in a stuck solution, so any movement to a solution would be great

Answer (score 0):

```js
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
           test: /\.mjs$/,
           include: /node_modules/,
           type: "javascript/auto"
         }
       ] 
     }
   }
}
```

I find this solution in [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71883314/5159120)

Works for me